# I need MSVCR90.dll version 9.0.21022.8

Tags: python, visual-c++, py2exe

According to a py2exe tutorial I found I need MSVCR90.dll version 9.0.21022.8 to run it for python 2.6. Where do I find MSVCR90.dll version 9.0.21022.8?

Comment: Somewhat relevant: Here's a tutorial with steps to extract the DLL from Visual Studio, if you want to bundle it right in without an extra dependency: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial#Step5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install the [VS 2008 redistrbutable package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9b2da534-3e03-4391-8a4d-074b9f2bc1bf&displaylang=en).

Comment: Probably it's rather better to download 2008 SP1 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a5c84275-3b97-4ab7-a40d-3802b2af5fc2 as far as `py2exe.exe.manifest` doesn't enforce strict versions equality

Comment: @abatishchev except that the 2008 SP1 is not 100% compatible with the non-SP1 version. This is precisely the issue I see now.